# MediaPlayer.OnPrepared() never called - playing stream

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, playback

I don't know what's wrong. **PrepareAsync()** is called, but neither **onPrepared()** or **onError()** get called. Already tested
on a **api28** emulator.
The streams tested are *https://streaming.sertaovibe.com.br/radio/8000/aac* or *http://144.217.31.171:8000*

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    public void play() {

    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    mPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
        new AudioAttributes
                    .Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build());
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnTimedMetaDataAvailableListener(this);

    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(getString(R.string.url_streaming));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        UpdateUIError();
    }
        mPlayer.prepareAsync();
        UpdateUIBuffering();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        UpdateUIBufferingComplete();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        UpdateUIError();
        return true;

    }

}
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: probably `mediaplayer` never reache state ´Prepared`. Use ` mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "whats happening);
            });` to find out whats happening while preparing

Comment: I have debugged and it passes trough mPlayer.prepareAsync().
LogCat shows nothing.
I'm really thinking that MediaPlayer doesn't work and I'm going to have to resort to an external library like AACDecoder

Comment: use `mPlayer.prepare()` instead of `mPlayer.prepareAsync()` and see whats happen and set log-steps after each command beginning of `mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` problem can also be in the beginning of your code

Comment: The only difference is that freezes the UI.

Comment: If `onPrepared()` is not called, the error is before this call. Try to find out what the last step in the Logcat output is